# How to disable browser back action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

On my aspx page, I have a tab control.
    In each tab I am loading an `Iframe` with URL. This `Iframe` URL is stored in a db table.
    Each tab has its own `Iframe`.
    Tabs are generated dynamically by reading a data in a table.
    When focus is on `Iframe` and user presses back button, it tries to load previous url in `Iframe` and gives `404 error`.
    How can I handle this backspace button case?
    Same thing happens when user click browser back button.

I tried capturing KeyCode on keydown event in `javascript` and set `window.location.href` to the same page.

This works well on parent page. But when focus is on tab content, I dont have any control over there.

Also for my parent page, I am disabling `cache` on `Page Init` event by

```
protected void Page_Init(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Is there any way to handle these two scenarios?

Comment: Window `keydown` event can be prevented using `preventDefault()` but it is not a good idea to hack browser back button functionality

Comment: You can use [onbeforeunload] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)